# Accessing .tfstate file in .tf file - terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to create a new WebApp resource into  existing resource group.
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439848/using-terraform-to-import-existing-resources-on-azure) and [this post](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/resource_group.html) explains how we can import existing resource ( instead of creating new one every time)

I was able to import my existing resource group using below command

```
terraform import azurerm_resource_group.rg-myResourceGroup /subscriptions/00000-my-subscription-id-0000000/resourceGroups/rg-myResourceGroup
```

After executing this command I can see new file is created named `'terraform.tfstate'` Below is content of the file.

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "terraform_version": "0.11.11",
    "serial": 1,
    "lineage": "-----------------------------",
    "modules": [
        {
            "path": [
                "root"
            ],
            "outputs": {},
            "resources": {
                "azurerm_resource_group.rg-ResourceGroupName": {
                    "type": "azurerm_resource_group",
                    "depends_on": [],
                    "primary": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/subscription-id-00000000000/resourceGroups/rg-hemant",
                        "attributes": {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/subscription-id-00000000000/resourceGroups/rg-hemant",
                            "location": "australiaeast",
                            "name": "rg-ResourceGroupName",
                            "tags.%": "0"
                        },
                        "meta": {},
                        "tainted": false
                    },
                    "deposed": [],
                    "provider": "provider.azurerm"
                }
            },
            "depends_on": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Now my question is how can I access/refer/include `terraform.tfstate` in my `main.tf`

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg-hemant" {
  #name = it should be rg-ResourceGroupName 
  #location = it should be australiaeast
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

1. Assume that in my subscription '`mysubscription1`' there is a
   resource group '`rg-exising`'
2. This resource group already have few resources e.g. `webapp1` ,
   `storageaccount1`
3. Now I want to write a terraform script which will add new
   resource ( e.g. newWebapp1 ) to existing resource group
   'rg-existing'
4. so after `terraform apply` operation `rg-exising` should have
   below resources

   - webapp1
   - storageaccount1
   - newWebapp1 ( added by new `terraform apply` script )

4) Note that I don't want terraform to create ( in case of `apply` )  OR delete ( in case of `destroy` ) my existing resources which belongs to `rg-exising`

Comment: What do you mean by access? Are you saying you want Terraform to start managing the resource group so it can modify it and delete it? Or because you want to be able to refer to it with other resources?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR , please look at Update 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dug more through the posts and found a solution [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12917).

We can use additional parameters to terraform destroy to specifically mentioned which resource we want to destroy

```
terraform destroy -target RESOURCE_TYPE.NAME -target RESOURCE_TYPE2.NAME
```

Note: What I have learnt is that, in this case there is no need to use `terraform import` command

Answer (score 1):

you dont really, you just need to map your resource to the state in tfstate, so just do:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg-hemant" {
  name = 'rg-ResourceGroupName'
  location = 'australiaeast'
}
```

and tf should recognize this resource as the one you have in the state file

Comment: Thanks, specifying name and location did add new resource to my existing resource group when I execute 'terraform apply' command.  But, when I execute terraform destroy' command it also destroyed my entire existing resource group.  Please have a look at my UPDATE 1

Comment: yeah, destroy will destroy the tf resource (resource group in this case), so everything in it.

Comment: Now onward we want to write terraform script to manage the new resources but we don't want to touch existing resources.  New resources that we want to create will be part of existing resource group and we don't want new terraform script to touch the old resources...

Comment: i'm not sure about this part, tbh (it might still complain about resources in resource group, but not in the tf configuration). but you should exclude resource group resource, if you want to destroy resources

Comment: honestly, you should just put those new resources into a separate resource group