# How to prevent the removal of a resource group when run terraform destroy?

Tags: azure, terraform

I have already created resource group(not created using my code).

I run terraform apply and my infra was created. But when I run terraform destroy - the console says that my resource group should be deleted too. This should not happen, because not only my infra is in this resource group.

I have try to use terraform import as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47446540/10912908 and got the same result as before.

Also, I have tried to define the resource group with only name, but it is not work(. Terraform destroy removes this resource

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "testgroup" {    
name = "Test-Group"    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to not include resource group resource in the configuration for the resource group to not be destroyed (as all the resources in the configuration are to be destroyed). if you rely on outputs from that resource you can use data resource instead.

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name = "Test-Group"
}
```

OP also needed to remove resource group from the state file.

Comment: This answer would be improved by a simple working example of how they can achieve this rather than importing the resource.

Comment: I assume it is what I need?
[link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/resource_group.html)

Comment: Just checked it, but it doesn't work. I think it causes because I previously deployed with the previous code, and now I did as you wrote

Comment: what doesnt work? if you replaced resource with this, you need to replace references to the resource as well.

Comment: that's right, I did it, but when I run terraform destroy the console says that the resource group will be deleted too

Comment: you sure you removed the resource group resource? it doesnt remove data resources 101%

Comment: btw, terraform apply removes resource group too

Comment: I did not confirm the destroy command, I just ran it to see what would be removed

Comment: I replaced the resource "azurerm_resource_group" ... to data "azurerm_resource_group" ... as you said, and updated links

Comment: ok, i'm not really sure what you are doing, unfortunately, but I do know that if you do not have the resource in the configuration it wont get deleted, maybe if you imported it - it might, since its not part of the configuration anymore. I'd suggest removing state files and trying again

Comment: You are right, I needs some actions with my state file. I only remove resource group from the state file with the following command: terraform state rm testgroup and after that I do not see the resource group in the list for deletion. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This bash script could work:

```
terraform state list | while read line
do 
if [[ $line == azurerm_resource_group* ]]; then
echo $line " is a resource group and will not be deleted!"
else
echo "deleting: " $line
terraform destroy -target $line -auto-approve
fi
done
```

It lists all resources which are managed by terraform and then runs a delete script for every entry except for lines containing "azurerm_resource_group*"